# Populating a ListBox from a Dataset gives me System.Data.Datarow or Blank

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have found many solutions for this but they all seem to lead to me having a blank `ListBox` or the `System.Data.DataRow` value being returned.

What I am trying to do is fill a `ListBox` with Data from a SQL query.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="List1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

C#:

```
queryString = "Select distinct [Title] from OneNetProtalError";

            using (SqlConnection connection =
                       new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
                var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                var ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);


                List1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
```

Using the above code gives me back the value `System.Data.DataRow`

if I follow the other instructions I have read and add the line.

```
List1.DisplayMemberPath = "Title"
```

to C# or do the XAML version.

```
<ListBox Name="List1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" />
```

Then the list box is just blank.

I checked my `DataSet` and it has a table, it has the field and it has rows with data in it.

I'm sure i'm missing something obvious, I am very new to XAML/WPF and a bit new to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource` to the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` instead of calling `AsEnumerable()` on it:

```
List1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: This did the Trick mm8, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
List1.SelectedValuePath= "Title"; 

List1.DisplayMemberPath= "Title";

List1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].AsDataView();
```

You need to set your value member as well. Also use dataview for ur itemsource

By the way the sequence above matters, or you will not get a successful databind

Comment: my bad missed the path

Comment: He has already set the DisplayMemberPath and there is no reason to set the SelectedValuePath for a value to be displayed.

Comment: i think he is trying to get a value which causes him to get a System.Data.DataRow